# Problem In C , i don't know why main can't read ''or_vectb''

Tags: c

I'm new in stackoerflow, this is my first question.
I'm not interested in the algorithm of the code , i want just know why the compiler report the error i wrote above.  The error is : *the error is

```
:/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccw8lUiZ.o: in function `main':
                  ex2.3.c:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `or_vectb'
/usr/bin/ld: ex2.3.c:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `or_vectb'
                 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*
```

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>  
    #include<ctype.h> 
    #define A  {9,7,7,5,5,3}
    #define l  6

    void or_vectb(int len,int *B[len]); 
    void crea_vetpunt(int len,int V[len],int *B[len]){
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
        B[i]= &(V[i]);
    };
    } 

    void printa_vettore_ptr(int len , int *B[len]){
    int i=0;
    printf ("il vettore B sta puntando a questi elementi : \n ");
    for (i=0; i<len; i++){
            printf("%d",*B[i]);

     }
       //funzione scambia 
     void scambia(int len, int *B[len],int i){
      int j= i+1;
      int * temp_ind;
      temp_ind=B[i];
      B[i]=B[j];
      B[j]=temp_ind;
      }


      // try to order the vect

     void or_vectb(int len,int *B[len]){
     int i,j;
     for (i=0; i<len; i++){
            for(j=0; j<len; j++){
            if(*(B[i])>*(B[i+1])){
                    scambia(len,B,i);
  
             }
             }
     }

     }
     }

     int main (void) {
     int len= l;
     int V[l]=A;
     int* B[l];
     crea_vetpunt(len, V,B);
     printa_vettore_ptr(len,B);
     or_vectb(len,B);
     printa_vettore_ptr(len,B);
     return 0;
      }
```

```
*the error is :/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccw8lUiZ.o: in function `main':
                  ex2.3.c:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `or_vectb'
/usr/bin/ld: ex2.3.c:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `or_vectb'
                 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status*
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should apply proper indentation to your code. It should immediately show the logical structure and the blocks in your code at first sight.

Comment: In standard C there are no nested function definitions allowed. If you use a compiler hat allows such a thing the scopes also apply to functions wrt visibility.

Comment: Remove the ```or_vectb``` pre-declaration in the 7th line and it should work better.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Re “In standard C there are no nested function definitions allowed”: The C standard defines two degrees of program conformance to the standard. C 4 5: “A *strictly conforming program* shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this document.” C 4 7: “A *conforming program* is one that is acceptable to a conforming implementation.” A conforming C implementation may allow extensions, so a conforming C program may use extensions defined by some compiler. So standard C allows nested function definitions (supported by GCC) in conforming programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definitions of the functions `scambia` and `or_vectb` appear inside the function `printa_vettore_ptr`. Nesting function definitions like that is a fancy feature for special purposes that is supported by some compilers as an extension to the C standard. You do not use any of those special purposes in this program and do not need these function definitions to be nested.

Move the definitions of `scambia` and `or_vectb` from inside `printa_vettore_ptr` to before or after `printa_vettore_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of mistakes in your code

the functions: scambia , or_vectb, are nested in the printa_vettore_ptr function
and in your principal program you called every function separately

so you should separate every function and call it separately , if you want to make only 1 function which scan and print and ... you just write your code without int main(......)/void main(....)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define A { 9 , 7 , 7 , 5 , 5 , 3 }
#define l 6

void or_vectb(int len,int *B[len]);
void crea_vetpunt(int len,int V[len],int *B[len]);
void printa_vettore_ptr(int len , int *B[len]);
void scambia(int *a, int *b);
void or_vectb(int len,int *B[len]);



int main (void)
{
   int len=l;
   int V[l]=A;
   int *B[l];
   crea_vetpunt(len, V,*B);
   printa_vettore_ptr(len,*B);
   or_vectb(len,*B);
   printa_vettore_ptr(len,*B);
   return 0;
}


void crea_vetpunt(int len,int V[len],int *B[len])
{
   for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
   {
       B[i]=&V[i];
   }
}

 void scambia(int *a, int *b)//I just reverse the adresses of a & b
 {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
 }

void printa_vettore_ptr(int len , int *B[len])
{

   printf ("\nil vettore B sta puntando a questi elementi : \n");
   for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
   {
       printf("[%d]",(*B[i]));
   }
}

void or_vectb(int len,int *B[len])
{
   for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
   {
        for(int j=i+1; j<len; j++)
        {
            if((B[i])<(B[j]))
            {
                scambia(&B[i],&B[j]);
            }
        }
   }
 }
```